# Trying to convert a list of tuples to a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

So I'm reading a CSV file with two columns, and then taking the product of all of them.

What I am trying to do is convert t his product from a list of tuples, to a list of lists. I ultimately want to combine each tuple into a string with a comma. Here's my code:

```
rowa = []
rowb = []

for row in csvfile:
    if row[0] != "":
        rowa.append(row[0])
    if row[1] != "":
        rowb.append(row[1])
wordlist = list(product(rowa, rowb))
```

And my pseudocode is this:

```
for x in wordlist:
    x = list(x)
    x.join(" ")
```

`print wordlist` should bring up a list of strings, which will be the old tuples, turned into a list and then joined together with a space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [join method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) works the other way around; call it on the space string:

```
for x in wordlist:
    " ".join(x)
```

It works on any sequence, so there is no need to convert tuples to lists here.

Note that you can dispense with the `!= ""` tests for your columns; the empty string is considered boolean False as well:

```
for row in csvfile:
    if row[0]:
        rowa.append(row[0])
    if row[1]:
        rowb.append(row[1])
```

Finally, because you are already iterating over the wordlist, just leave it a generator and dispense with the list call altogether.

```
wordlist = [" ".join(x) for x in product(rowa, rowb)]
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to create intermediate list

```
rowa = []
rowb = []

for row in csvfile:
    row0,row1 = row[0].lower(),row1.lower()
    if row0 != row1:
        if row[0] != "":
             rowa.append(row0)
        if row[1] != "":
             rowb.append(row1)
wordlist = product(rowa, rowb)

result = [" ".join(x) for x in wordlist]
```

a generator expression should do the job

**EDIT**
additional requirements

Comment: Also, what would be a good way of making all of these values lowercase? I tried row[0].lower but it seems to somehow convert it into the string method, not make everything lowercase.

Comment: Surprising `rowa.append(row[0].lower())` should do the job

Comment: I need to do it before then though, as I added another condition, if row[0] != row[1]: and I want everything to be the same case beforehand.

Comment: if you want all the string being lowercase you should do also `rowb.append(row[1].lower()`

Comment: Ok, but I need to compare the strings, they need to be lowercase, all of them, BEFORE the comparison, otherwise I will have duplicates (i.e., Wordpress wordpress, which would then be turned into wordpress wordpress, but they'd still be duplicate)

Comment: The comparison happens before the append.

Comment: if row[0] != row[1]:
                            rowa.append(row[0])

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much guessing what you mean, but are you trying to zip two lists?

```
wordlist = zip(rowa, rowb)
```